# when i use query builder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have three tables users , posts and comment i want to get all posts and all comment for this posts when i use query builder join returned only posts that have a comment in comments table

```
$collection = DB::table('post')
    ->join('comment','post.id','comment.post_id')
    ->join('users','users.id','comment.commenter_id')
    ->orderBy('time', 'DESC')
    ->get()->all();
```

how can i return all posts or if you have another  way to do it tell me pleas

Comment: You need to use `leftJoin()` instead of `join()`

Comment: thank you pro  can i ask another question

Comment: Feel free to edit your question if you have to ask something else which is related to this or create a new question if it's unrelated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left join.
It returns all the records from left table whether joining table has records or not.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

```
$collection = DB::table('post')
        ->leftJoin('comment','post.id','comment.post_id')
        ->leftJoin('users','users.id','comment.commenter_id')
        ->orderBy('time', 'DESC')
        ->get()->all();
```

Comment: but this query get posts for example post with id 1 have tow comment in the result collection i find tow item to this post for each  comment has one item in collection can i get all comment in one item ?

Comment: That you can`t do, That`s two records.